# Returning 404 for expired jobs in my jobs site

Tags: seo, 404

In my new Job search site how should I handle jobs which are expired?

Ideally those should return  410 response when deleted. But I'd like to delete them(404 response) since that'd be easy to do for my Drupal site.

Will it cause any problems?

I'm placing some links to similar discussions:

[link1](http://hrsearchmarketing.com/recruitment-seo-best-practices-for-handling-expired-job-postings/)

[link2](https://moz.com/community/q/best-way-to-handle-expired-content)

[link3](http://moz.com/blog/how-should-you-handle-expired-content)

[link4](http://graywolfseo.com/seo/expired-product-auction-pages/)

Comment: Look at [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/44629/seo-handling-of-ever-changing-portion-of-site/44631#44631), it is very similar.

Comment: It is the same question I'm looking for. I'd like to delete this question.

Answer (score 3):

I think using .htaccess to 301 redirect to a generic related page would work best. Something like, "Thanks for coming by, this job is no longer active. Feel free to look at our other current positions ."

Answer (score 1):

Regarding visitors, I think returning [custom 404](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136085) is better and fun.

Regarding SEO, I think making [301 redirect](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) to the most appropriate page is better to transfer PR from the deleted page.

Choose what you prefer but I advise you to think to your visitors before SEO (even if SEO is important).

Look at [what stackexchange do](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/page-not-found/).